# Cesium Viewer vs. Cesium Widget. Which one should I use?

Tags: cesiumjs

I using Cesium in my application. My application shows billboard on the map accordingly with received positions.

I would like to know the difference between `Cesium.Viewer` and `Cesium.CesiumWidget`. Is it possible to create entities using Cesium Widget? What is the advantage of using the `Cesium.CesiumWidget`? Does it gives me the same functionality as `Cesium.Viewer` but without all the extra widgets (such as timeline)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `Cesium.Viewer` includes the `Cesium.CesiumWidget` to render the globe itself.  `Viewer` wraps `CesiumWidget` along with the other widgets (timeline, baselayerpicker, etc).  `Viewer` also adds some extra logic for managing a list of dataSources, a clock, etc.

Generally if you're doing more than drawing a few graphics primitives, you should use `Viewer` not `CesiumWidget`, and just turn off the widgets you don't need via the viewer's [constructor options](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Viewer.html).

Comment: Viewer allows me more functionality regarding entities and animation of those entities, right? Could I get these kind of thing working just with the widget?

Comment: Viewer has [a bunch of logic](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.16/Source/Widgets/Viewer/Viewer.js#L1317-L1364) to support entities, particularly when used with `SelectionIndicator` and `InfoBox`, and for following entities with the camera (`EntityView`).  Still you may be able to manage a DataSourceCollection [the way Viewer does](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.16/Source/Widgets/Viewer/Viewer.js#L356-L366) and get it to appear.